# JavaScript - htaccess - ErrorDocument - url rewrite - get variables from rewritten URI

Tags: javascript, .htaccess

I have a "client-side" problem regarding retrieval of variables from a re-written request. There must be a simple way to achieve this, I just don't know how.

The objective is to have JavaScript (client-side) handle server "error" responses, like: 403, or 404.

These are the relevant code snippets that I have:

**.htaccess**

```
ErrorDocument 404 /lib/dbug.htm?fail=404
```

**JavaScript**

```
console.log(document.location.search)
```

When I test it in the browser, with i.e: `apache.dev/foo.bar` - the console log shows an empty string.

I understand this is because the current "document path" is "/foo.bar" - with no query-string at all; however, the response URL was rewritten as shown above.

There may be issues with my `.htaccess` code, and if so, please advise?
I think that the problem could be solved by somehow setting a response-header in the `.htaccess` and retrieve that with JavaScript, somehow.. Either that or somehow get the `document.responseCode` ?

- Is it possible to retrieve the re-written query-string from anywhere?
- If not, can I set a header in the .htaccess and have JavaScript retrieve this?

Been at this for hours, no luck. If anyone has an idea of how to achieve this, I would appreciate the input.

Comment: Might be good idea to explain why you need client side to handle server errors in the first place. Higher level objective is not clear at all. Also what server side programming language are you using? Is it set to compile `.htm` files?

Comment: Doesn't answer the other questions or exactly how you expect this to work. If use server side programming language to access your `fail` query param issue is trivial

Comment: Thanks, yes, you're right, "client-side only" is the objective, with the only server-side being the server configuration. It is to minimize server-side work-load, not my idea, but from my boss; something to do with C10K problems, and ways to resolve it with low-cost not only in development time but mainly to reduce the need for more routers/servers in the data-center for load-balancing.

Comment: Really can't be serious that the amount of processing to output a simple file that parses a GET param is going to save anything significant regarding workload....especially only for error pages. Would allow you to set js variables in that file also. Sounds a bit like picking up dust when the task is to clean up a whole landfill

Comment: What is that query param currently doing anyway? What is in `dbug.htm`?

Comment: Indeed, it would be very quick to get/set these with a server-side language, even JavaScript (NodeJS) -or PHP, etc, however; this is the problem -to handle it client-side.

Comment: That query-param "fail" simply sets a get-variable, and the "dbug.htm" file runs some checks (using JavaScript), including checking for errors from the server, and displays an appropriate message. These error messages are uniform, handled by the same dbug.htm - so we can edit the styling and debug checks in one place.

Comment: OK...so it is already being compiled by server side language...can simply set javascript variables based on same GET

Comment: @charlietfl :: I agree that it is quite a challenge, but, every bit helps. The servers I'm targeting are overloaded most of the time, so, we're devising ways to limit requests, converting to single-page-apps that only requires bootstrapping the client-side (once per visitor session) and no recurring requests needed for styles, fonts, graphics, etc; only small text based templates that instruct the client-side to "draw" the view.

Comment: Sure, injecting javascript from server-side could work, still, we need to abstract as much as possible away from the server, so much that the only things we need the server for is to "serve & save" files & data.

Comment: Have you considered an `error` virtual directory then and use htaccess to output static htm file but with various errors also in url? Like `error/404` ... would all be same html file and you simply parse `location.path` into your js single page app. Then the only server workload is the htaccess and serving the html and basic static resources

Comment: good idea! that could work!

Comment: Will you show me how to do that - as an answer? .. (please <- magic word)